# ImportError when trying to import a module in Sublime Text 2 (Python)

Tags: python, import, sublimetext2, python-module

I downloaded xlwings online, and I've been trying to get it to work within Sublime Text 2. When I type in import xlwings into IDLE, it works perfectly. However, when I do the same in Sublime Text 2, it says "ImportError: No module named xlwings."
The xlwings folder is installed in C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xlwings. Here is what I have for python.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH":"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages"
},
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "target": "console_exec"
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try removing `"env"` and its contents and see if it works. It's not necessary.

Comment: I tried this, but the same error keeps happening.

Comment: Try removing the `"target"` line to run the build using Sublime's default `exec` build. If it works there, then there's an issue with your `console_exec.py` file.

Comment: Tried this; still not working. Is it maybe a problem with the paths/file locations?

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Python installed? Also, how did you install `xlwings`? I just installed it for 2.7 and 3.4, fired up [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) (I'm using ST3, BTW), and importing it worked fine...

Comment: What happens if you run your `.py` file from the command line?

Comment: Hey, so I got it to work! I just needed to run the .py file. Thanks!